# Access component data in other component using slots in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a VueJS component. I have two other components which I want to use in a parent child manner. Now, I want to pass parent's data to child. It is like this:

> App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <parent>
            <child></child>
            <child></child>
            <child></child>
            <child></child> 
        </parent>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import child from './child.vue'
    import parent from './parent.vue'

    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        parent,
        child
      }
    })  
</script>
```

> parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        This is parent component
        <slot>
        </slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'parent',
        data () {
            return {
                parentMsg: {
                    'key1': 'value1',
                    'key2': 'value2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> child.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      Child component
      <!-- I have to place a div here which will consume parentMsg object -->
      <!-- Each instance of child component rendered should have access to parentMsg -->
      <div>
         <!-- Some HTML to consume the parentMsg -->  
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        name: 'child',
        data () {
            return {
                demo: 'Demo message changed'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want `parentMsg` from `parent.vue` to be accessible in `child.vue`. I don't want to expose `parentMsg` on `App.vue`. How can I do this?
I placed the `div` consuming parentMsg inside (and after too) unnamed slot in parent.vue template and thought that with each instance of child.vue, a copy of div will be rendered. It does not work.

Comment: Why dont you put the child-component in the parent template and pass the msg from parent to them ? Slots are not intended to be used like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you put the child-component in the parent template and pass the msg from parent to them ? Slots are not intended to be used like this.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <parent>
        </parent>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import parent from './parent.vue'

    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        parent,
        child
      }
    })  
</script>
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        This is parent component
        <child :msg="key1"></child>
        <child :msg="key1"></child>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import child from './child.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'parent',
        data () {
            return {
                parentMsg: {
                    'key1': 'value1',
                    'key2': 'value2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      Child component
      <div>
         {{msg}}
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        name: 'child',
        props: {
          msg: String
        },
        data () {
            return {
                demo: 'Demo message changed'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a little different. I have created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5oc1rgq/14/
You can see that slots in root component are not getting plugged into respective child components. Any idea?

Comment: Ok first What i Can see is that you insert DOM elements inside your #app element this is totally wrong you first Mount a root vue component to the #app element

Comment: ill give you a jsfiddle soon

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have added a new question for the same too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344908/named-slots-in-nested-components-in-vuejs

You can see it for more details.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: well i can help you tomorrow. I suggest to use vue cli since the boilerplate is really cool
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: Thanks, The issue is solved now. I will post the solution in above question's link itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass data in slot in parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        This is parent component
        <slot :parentMsg="parentMsg"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

In app.vue access parentMsg through scope and pass as props to child:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <parent>
           <template scope="defaultSlotScope">
            <child :msg="defaultSlotScope.parentMsg"></child>
            <child :msg="defaultSlotScope.parentMsg"></child>
            <child :msg="defaultSlotScope.parentMsg"></child>
            <child :msg="defaultSlotScope.parentMsg"></child>
          </template>
        </parent>
    </div>
</template
```

>

In child.vue use msg as props:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
         {{msg}}  
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        name: 'child',
        props:['msg'],
        data () {
            return {
                demo: 'Demo message changed'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kumar_14 for your answer.